# create a simple extjs combo box without auto-complete feature

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am trying to create a simple extjs3.4 combo box without the auto-complete feature.

below is my code and link jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E5wyx/

the problem with the code below is that, after any item in the list is selected, then there is no way to choose another one. not sure what config option I should use. thanks.

```
    var cb = new Ext.form.ComboBox({

        width: 60,
        typeAhead: false,
        mode: "local",
        displayField: 'name',
        editable: false,
        renderTo:"cont1",              
        store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: ['name'],
            data  : [
                     ['option 1'], 
                     ['option 2'], 
                     ['option 3'], 
                     ['option 4'],
                     ['option 5']
                    ]
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following `options: lastQuery: '',  triggerAction: 'all'`
and that make the combo box behaves just like an ordinary

http://jsfiddle.net/E5wyx/3/